# AccessibilityService in Monodroid

Tags: xamarin.android

Simple question... quite possibly not simple answers :)

I want to write an accessibility service for android in monodroid.  I'm finding it difficult to work out the pieces.  I can inherit from `AccessibilityService`, but there isn't an AccessibilityServiceAttribute.  I need specific content in the manifest file, but apparently the intent filter and service xml is not directly supported by monodroid... I believe.

I doubt this is something that many people have done, but as a beginner with Monodroid, I think I'm mainly just finding it difficult to put together the well supported "normal" app development, with the "supported" but not quite, accessibility service development.

I would appreciate any pointers.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html):

> An accessibility is declared as any other service in an AndroidManifest.xml but it must also specify that it handles the "android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" Intent. Failure to declare this intent will cause the system to ignore the accessibility service.

Since it is declared the same way as any other service, you can make use of [ServiceAttribute](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=T%3aAndroid.App.ServiceAttribute) and [IntentFilterAttribute](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=T%3aAndroid.App.IntentFilterAttribute) to generate the entry in AndroidManifest.xml. For example:

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" })]
public class MyAccessibilityService : AccessibilityService
{
    public override void OnAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent e)
    {

    }

    public override void OnInterrupt()
    {
    }
}
```

When you build the application, Mono for Android will generate this in the manifest:

```
<service android:name="sample.MyAccessibilityService">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```